# Pandas: Sort a subset under certain conditions

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, subset

I have two data frames, one contains information about employees and the other contains information about projects. They look like this:

```
df_employees.head(5)

      id    name    salary
 0  0469    Aurore  18100
 1  4c13    Malinda 16100
 2  67f2    Cephus  20500
 3  7b36    Doctor  16000
 4  5c65    Paloma  27100

df_projects.head(5)

    employee_id project_id  start_date  end_date
 0  8411    03245e5933eb    2017-03-16  2017-03-30
 1  b67d    033af173480e    2017-02-27  2017-04-06
 2  5ca8    033af173480e    2017-02-27  2017-04-06
 3  bb0c    03fa66f3a3e8    2020-06-12  None
 4  6d22    03fa66f3a3e8    2020-06-12  None
```

Now I am trying to find the 3 lowest paid employees who have done at least 10 projects. For this, I started by merging both datasets, as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df_mer = pd.merge(df_employees, df_projects, left_on= 'id', right_on= 'employee_id')

print(df_mer.head(10))

     id     name  salary employee_id    project_id  start_date    end_date
 0  0469   Aurore   18100        0469  0bd005702cc1  2020-06-17  2020-08-02
 1  0469   Aurore   18100        0469  8b2ce1e01e29  2018-02-05  2018-02-21
 2  0469   Aurore   18100        0469  d580afd6f249  2020-07-04  2020-07-28
 3  4c13  Malinda   16100        4c13  05b299e8ecd9  2018-02-06  2018-03-13
 4  4c13  Malinda   16100        4c13  42c7826cb8e1  2019-02-08  2019-05-21
 5  4c13  Malinda   16100        4c13  64e01cf58730  2018-04-28  2018-07-10
 6  4c13  Malinda   16100        4c13  7854dcf39808  2019-12-05        None
 7  4c13  Malinda   16100        4c13  8505058db062  2018-04-11  2018-05-29
 8  4c13  Malinda   16100        4c13  908c863bccdd  2019-02-04  2019-05-14
 9  4c13  Malinda   16100        4c13  c7bb3ababa5c  2018-02-18  2018-10-12
```

Then I wrote this command to obtain the number of projects done by each employee:

```
vn = df_mer['name'].value_counts()
vn.head(5)
Arielle     15
Cornell     10
Devonta     10
Phylicia    10
Abigail      9
```

Now I would like to find the 3 lowest paid employees who have done at least 10 projects, but I have no idea as to how to do it. If someone could give me a hint I would be very grateful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vn = df_mer['name'].value_counts()
a=vn[vn > 10].index.tolist()
b=df_mer[df_mer['name'].isin(a)].drop_duplicates(subset='name',keep='first')
c=b.nsmallest(3, 'salary')

3_lowest_paid_employees=c.name
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Shuvashish, your answer works, I just had to replace `a=vn[vn > 10].index.tolist()` with `a=vn[vn > 9].index.tolist()` to obtain exatly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Could you try using nsmallest for the first df. Something like

```
df_employees.nsmallest(3,'salary')
```

and group by employee and counting the projects on the second

```
df_projects.groupby('employee_id')['project_id'].count()
```

Filter the results having above 10 and merging these back together ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works well but the answer of @Shuvashish is more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

I would order your operations a little differently. You can count the number of projects an employee has performed from df_projects before merging:

```
from datetime import date

# You may want to filter by completed projects and future projects
mask = ~df_projects["end_date"].isnull()
mask &= df_projects["start_date"] <= pd.to_datetime(date.today())
n_projects = df_projects.loc[mask, "employee_id"].value_counts()
n_projects.name = "n_projects"

# Reindex employee dataframe by employee id
df_employees.set_index("id", drop=True, inplace=True)

# Left Join
df = df_employees.join(n_projects, how="left")
```

The output looks something like this, but I used an outer join because none of the ids matched from the sample data provided:

```
        name    salary  n_projects
0469    Aurore  18100.0 NaN
4c13    Malinda 16100.0 NaN
5c65    Paloma  27100.0 NaN
5ca8    NaN     NaN     1.0
67f2    Cephus  20500.0 NaN
7b36    Doctor  16000.0 NaN
8411    NaN     NaN     1.0
b67d    NaN     NaN     1.0
```

Then you can proceed to easily sort and filter...

```
project_limit = 10
df[df["n_projects"] >= project_limit].sort_values(
    by=["salary", "n_projects"],
    ascending=[True, False]
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but the previous answer gives the intended result more efficiently.